# Computational Geometric Aspects of Greedy Tour Expansion

Tags: discrete-geometry, computational-geometry, plane-geometry, heuristics

Has the following problem already been investigated from the Computational Geometry point of view and what are the results regarding worst case complexity?

> Given
>
> - a finite set $\mathcal{P}$ of $n$ distinct points in the Euclidean plane,
> - its convex hull $\mathcal{T_{\text{card(CH(}\mathcal{P}\text{))}}}\ :=\ \text{CH(}\mathcal{P}\text{)}$ as the initial tour.
>
> while $m<n$
>
> - chose $\ \left( p\in\mathcal{P}\setminus\mathcal{T_m},\ t_i\in\mathcal{T_m}\right):$
>     $\quad\quad\quad\|p-t_i\|+\|t_{\text{succ(}i\text{)}}-p\|-\|t_{\text{succ(}i\text{)}}-t_i\|$ $\quad\le\quad\|q-t_k\|+\|t_{\text{succ(}k\text{)}}-q\|-\|t_{\text{succ(}k\text{)}}-t_k\|$
>     $\forall q\in\mathcal{P}\setminus\mathcal{T_m},\quad\left(t_k,t_{\text{succ(}k\text{)}}\right)\in\mathcal{T_m}$
> - $\mathcal{T_{m+1}} := \lbrace\mathcal{T_m}\setminus\left(t_{\text{i}},t_{\text{succ(}i\text{)}}\right)\rbrace\cup\lbrace\left(t_i,p\right),\left(p,t_{\text{succ(}i\text{)}}\right)\rbrace$
>
> in this context, $t_{\text{succ(}i\text{)}}$ shall denote the tour-vertex that is encountered immediately after vertex $t_\text{i}$ when traversing the tour w.l.o.g in counter clockwise order.

Please note, that the objective of the task is *not* to create a simple polygon through all points or even an optimal tour; it is rather to determine the point, whose integration into the tour incurs the least length-increase, as fast as possible.

I am looking for techniques from Computational Geometry, i.e. algorithms and datastructures, that bring about provable improvements beyond updating least detour information w.r.t. the newly generated edges after the insertion of a further point.

Here is an example of a selfintersecting tour with 50 points, that was generated with the greedy insertion algorithm, answering a question of Joseph O'Rourke:

[image: Selfintersecting Tour]

**Addendum 2018-02-11:**

to indicate, that geometric concepts may indeed be promising, consider the problem of deciding, whether a point $p\notin \mathcal{T_i}$ is closer (in the sense of incurred elongation) to tour edge $(t_i,t_j)$ or to $(t_j,t_k)$.

in that special case, where the tour edges are adjacent, the separator equals the [radical axis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radical_axis) of the circles with center and radius $(t_i,\|t_j-t_i\|)$ and $(t_k,\|t_k-t_j\|)$; whether that is an actual improvement, depends of course on the computational model and the limitations on available resources - for very large instances it may not be viable to store all distances between pairs of points, whence deciding on which side of the radical line a point lies, is cheaper than calculating and comparing two detours.

for non-adjacent tour edges the situation is not so simple and yields non-linear algebraic curves as separators in general.

Answer (score 1):

Let $P$ be the original set of points, and $P'$ those not yet in the tour.
Compute for each edge $e_i=(t_i,t_{i+1})$ the length increase if $e_i$ stretches
to each $p \in P'$. Store all these in a heap.

Take off the min stretch, say from $e_i$ to $p$, and insert $p$ into the
tour, and remove $p$ from $P'$. Now you need to remove from the heap all
those entries matching an edge $e_j$ to this $p$, as $p$ is no longer available.
So this costs $|P'|$. Next you need to insert into the heap new entries
for the two new edges $(t_i,p)$ and $(p,t_{i+1})$, matching with
each point in $P'$. This costs $\log |P'|$.

I think the overall cost is then $O(n^2 \log n)$, where $n=|P|$, 
likely not what you want.
Consider this the naive algorithm to improve.

---

[image: Tour10]

          

<sup>Red point is incorporated into the tour.</sup>

---

It would be interesting to find an example that does not result in a simple polygon, or prove that the algorithm always does result in a simple polygon.

---

***Added***. This confirms Manfred's comment that the path can be non-simple.

---

[image: TourCrossing]

          

<sup>A crossing path, $n=50$.</sup>

---

Comment: The use of one of the heap variants is of course better than calculating the detours for each pair of insertion candidate and tour edge; what I had in mind, was something like a Voronoi Diagram. "Filling" the heap initially requires calculating the detours of each pair of candidate vertex and edge of the initial tour; that is however not necessary.  The tours that are generated with the greedy least expansion are almost surely not simple for $n>50$ points that are iid in the unit square. I have implemented that strategy and was initially also convinced that it would generate simple polygons.

Comment: @ManfredWeis: Yes, some Voronoi-diagram like structure would be necessary to beat quadratic time complexity.