# Complexity of tour-expansion heuristic for the planar Euclidean TSP

Tags: discrete-geometry, computational-geometry, plane-geometry, heuristics

This is a followup question to this one: [Computational Geometric Aspects of Greedy Tour Expansion](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/292642/computational-geometric-aspects-of-greedy-tour-expansion).

Assume that the candidate point, whose insertion into current incurs the least tour-length increase, is determined as follows:

- identify for each candidate point $p_i$ the nearest tour point $t_j$ and take as the minimal tour-elongation incurred by inserting $p_i$ into the tour  $$\min\left(\|p_i-t_{j-1}\|+\|t_j-p_i\|-\|t_j-t_{j-1}\|,\ \|p_i-t_j\|+\|t_{j+1}-p_i\|-\|t_{j+1}-t_j\|\right)$$
- insert $p_{i_0}$ that yields the minimal tour-elongation according to the above calculation by replacing the tour-edge for which that minimum is attained.

The nearest tour-point query can be efficiently answered if the Voronoi diagram of the tour-points is available and the containing Voronoi cells of the candidate points have been identified; updating the Voronoi diagram after inserting a point into the tour can also be done efficiently, cf. e.g. [Incremental Voronoi diagrams](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~srallen/papers/incremental-voronoi.pdf) and identifying the candidate points that lie within the newly generated Voronoi cell amounts to scrutinizing the canidate points in the two adjacent Voronoi cells of the tour-vertices adjacent to the replaced tour-edge.

> **Questions:**
>
> - Does the sketched "nearest tour-point" method of identifying the optimal candidate for tour expansion actually yield the optimal combination of candidate-point and tour-edge for insertion?
> - What would the worst and average case complexities of tour-expansion heuristics be, that are based on the nearest tour-point method of identifying optimal tour expansion and utilizing computational geometry concepts as sketched above?
> - Is the reduction of distance calculations, resp. the reduction of memory for storing calculated distances of interest for very large instances of Euclidean TSPs?